# How to specify a higher ruby version for installing a gem?

Tags: software-installation, ruby, gem

I install a ruby package.

```
$ sudo gem install pdfbeads
ERROR:  Error installing pdfbeads:
    nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

says that it needs ruby version greater than 1.9.1.

My ruby is 1.8.7.

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
$ gem --version
1.8.15
```

I have ruby 1.9.1 and 1.9.3.

```
$ whereis ruby1.9.1
ruby1.9: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3 /usr/bin/X11/ruby1.9.1 /usr/bin/X11/ruby1.9.3
```

but 1.9.3 is linked to 1.9.1.

```
$ ls /usr/bin/ruby* -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Jul 10 02:33 /usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5504 Nov 26  2013 /usr/bin/ruby1.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5552 Nov 26  2013 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Nov 26  2013 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3 -> ruby1.9.1
```

It says itself is 1.9.3 however:

```
$  /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3 --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
```

I change the link to ruby1.9.3 anyway

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/ruby*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Aug 20 21:16 /usr/bin/ruby -> ruby1.9.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5504 Nov 26  2013 /usr/bin/ruby1.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5552 Nov 26  2013 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Nov 26  2013 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3 -> ruby1.9.1
```

The installation still says it needs ruby >= 1.9.2

```
$ sudo gem install pdfbeads
ERROR:  Error installing pdfbeads:
    nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
$ gem --version
1.8.15
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
```

Do I have ruby1.9.3 or just ruby1.9.1?

How can I make `sudo gem install pdfbeads` use  ruby 1.9.3?

---

**Update:**

I have now followed the way of installing ruby 2.1.0 by RVM, 
I have added the path of `rvm` to my `PATH`.
I then successfully installed ruby2.1.0 by

```
$ rvm install 2.1.0
```

and made it default

```
$ rvm use 2.1.0

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]
$ which ruby
/home/tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
```

Now back to install the package `pdfbeads`, but without `sudo` (because I thought I had installed ruby 2.1.0 under my account, not under root, and installation of the package requires the newer version ruby)

```
$ gem install pdfbeads
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.8 directory.
```

So I think I have to use `sudo`. But I still get the original error,

```
$ sudo gem install pdfbeads

ERROR:  Error installing pdfbeads:
    nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

I think it is because under `sudo`, the user is `root`, which still has the older version ruby1.8.7 as the default. So I wonder what can I do now?

Comment: Is `rvm` path is in root's `PATH`?

Comment: `rvm` is in `$PATH`. I am not sure what you mean by "root's `PATH`". are there other's `PATH`?

Comment: I mean `PATH` when you are root.

Comment: It is not. Will it work if I switch to root, and add rvm path to the root's PATH by `PATH=$PATH:/home/tim/.rvm/bin`? I will have to switch back to my account, and install `pdfbeads`.

Comment: Shall I install rvm and ruby under the home of the root?

Comment: Confirm you're using the gem from one of your rvm rubies. `type gem`.

Comment: Avoid using sudo when installing gems

Comment: Also make sure that the rvm line is the LAST line of your .bashrc  The line is: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: @MichaelDurrantn (1) without `sudo`, `You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.8 directory.` Do you suggest using `sudo` or not? (2) Why "make sure that the rvm line is the LAST line of your `.bashrc`"?  If in the future I add something to `.bashrc`, should I append that  thing before or after `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`? What if everything wants to be at the end of the `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may wish to consider using a ruby package manager like rvm or rbenv

You can install different rubies and switch between them easily.

You might also want to consider trying 2.0+

Sample output from rvm:

```
21:59:48 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm 
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

21:59:50 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm 
$ rvm use 2.0.0
Using /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481

$ rvm use 2.1.1
Using /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1

$ rvm use 1.9.3
ruby-1.9.3-p547 is not installed.

$ rvm use 1.9.3-p448
Using /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

Get rvm at http://rvm.io/

Install with its famous 1 liner:

$  `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Comment: Thanks. I am now trying what you suggest. Btw, ruby1.9.3 is a symlink, linking to 1.9.1. Bu why it says itself is 1.9.3?

Comment: Why is ruby1.9.3 I installed not working?

Comment: Still get "nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2" error, after installing ruby 2.1.0. I update my post at its end.

Answer (score 2):

Install RVM and use the following:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
gem install pdfbeads  # Avoid sudo, will not fix real problems here.
```