# Does sudo a command temporarily change $PATH to be the root's?

Tags: sudo, path

1. When running `sudo <command>` under a user login session, will that
   change `$PATH` to be the root's `$PATH` during the running of `sudo
   <command>`?
2. If `<command>` relies on the user's `$PATH`, not the root's `$PATH`,
   how can the user run `sudo <command>` successfully?

   - One way is to `sudo su` to be the root,  change the root's
     `$PATH`  to be the user's, and run `<command>` directly. This is how I solved my problem of
     [How to specify a higher ruby version for installing a gem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151281/how-to-specify-a-higher-ruby-version-for-installing-a-gem).
   - Any way simpler?
   - Can it be done without switching to the root from the user?

Comment: Rusian asnwered you, but if you can use `sudo su` use `sudo su -`

Comment: why if you can use sudo su use sudo su -. What does that - mean?

Comment: @Tim - see the man page for `su`. It explains what the `-` does. It's a shorthand for `-l` or `--login`.

Comment: You can answer your own question by looking at the result of `sudo echo $PATH` . I actually did this, and it had not changed for me. But `sudo whoami` did return `root`. Those two results did surprise me somewhat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually [configuration-dependent](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html). There is an `env_reset` option in `sudoers` that, combined with `env_check` and `env_delete`, controls whether to replace, extend, or pass through some or all environment variables, including `PATH`.

The default behaviour is to have `env_reset` enabled, and to reset `PATH`. The value `PATH` is set to can be controlled with the `secure_path` option, and otherwise it is determined by the user configuration.

You can disable `env_reset` or add `PATH` to `env_keep` to change that behaviour, but note that it may not have the effect you want overall - there are often directories (`sbin`) in root's `PATH` that aren't in your user's. You can enable `setenv` instead to allow overriding environment for a single execution of `sudo` using the [`-E` option to `sudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo.man.html).

All of these could be changed in your distribution's default configuration already. Run `sudo visudo` to have a look at what's currently in your `sudoers` file.

---

There are alternative approaches. One simple one is to use `sudo`'s built-in environment variable setting or [`env`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html):

```
sudo PATH="$PATH" command ...
sudo env PATH="$PATH" command ...
```

will both run just this command with your current user's `PATH`. You can set other variables there as well in the same way, which is often useful. One or other of those may be disallowed by your configuration.

Answer (score 9):

> When running sudo  under a user login session, will that
>   change $PATH to be the root's $PATH during the running of sudo
>   ?

`sudo` will change `$PATH` variable, depend on your security policy. From `sudo` [man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html):

```
PATH
    May be overridden by the security policy.
```

In most system, `env_reset` option is enabled by default, this causes commands to be executed with a minimal environment containing `TERM`, `PATH`, `HOME`, `SHELL`, `LOGNAME`, `USER` and `USERNAME` in addition to variables from the invoking process permitted by the `env_check` and `env_keep` sudoers options.

For security reason, `/etc/sudoers` has `secure_path` option to set the safe `PATH` for `sudo`:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

> If  relies on the user's $PATH, not the root's $PATH, how can
>   the user run sudo  successfully?

Because the user's `PATH` can be preserved when you run `sudo`. You can always do:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" <command>
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you need to get an interactive login root shell?

`sudo -H -i`

from `man sudo`:

```
 -H          The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the
             target user (root by default) as specified by the password database.  Depending on the policy, this may be the default
             behavior.


 -i [command]
             The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a
             login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a
             command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified,
             an interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell.  The
             security policy shall initialize the environment to a minimal set of variables, similar to what is present when a user
             logs in.  The Command Environment section in the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the environment
             in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.
```