# Exported Date Variable not appearing in subshell

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables, timeout, subshell

I'm currently working on creating 2 bashes with two different scripts which result in two files named with the same timestamp for easy comparison/processing later. The date variable gets created in the first sh and I try to create an environment for it to get passed onto the second sh so that it can us the same timestamp. I'm using **timeout** because the second script is a looping process which inputs data to the file continuously until it is killed.

**1.sh**

```
current_date_time="`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S`"
code 
OUTPUT=$current_date_time --ouput-format csv
(export current_date_time; sudo timeout 15 2.sh)
```

**2.sh**

```
echo "The variable is $current_date_time"
call loop
  code
  OUTPUT=$current_date_time.txt
loop
```

The first script functions normally while the second one only results in the phrase `The variable is` while the output file fails to get made. My suspicion is on timeout but any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your sudoers policy preserve arbitrary environment variables? what happens if you change the command to `sudo -E timeout 15 2.sh`?

Comment: @steeldriver Yea that seems to have been the oversight. It works as I hoped now thanks!

Comment: @steeldriver, that comment sounds like The Answer; will you post it? Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller I've added a brief answer below - TBH I'm not entirely familiar with the details

Answer (score 2):

As noted in `man sudoers`:

> ```
>    Command environment
>      Since environment variables can influence program behavior, sudoers pro‐
>      vides a means to restrict which variables from the user's environment are
>      inherited by the command to be run.  There are two distinct ways sudoers
>      can deal with environment variables.
>
>      By default, the env_reset option is enabled.  This causes commands to be
>      executed with a new, minimal environment.
> ```

You can request for the calling environment to be preserved by invoking `sudo` with the `-E` or `--preserve-env` option:

```
sudo -E timeout 15 2.sh
```

(although this may be unsuccessful, if the sudoers policy forbids it).

Comment: It is a complex interplay of several configuration variables; https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151315/117549 is one answer here, but the key parts to navigate are: env_reset, env_keep, env_check, and env_delete. It wouldn't hurt to have a good canonical question on sudo environment-variable behavior here.